# Plotting 2D data using Xarray takes a surprisingly long time?

Tags: python, netcdf, dask, python-xarray

I am reading NetCDF files using xarray. Each variable have 4 dimensions (**Times, lev, y, x**). After reading the variable, I calculate the ***mean*** of the variable ***QVAPOR*** along (**Times,lev**) dimensions. After calculation I get variable ***QVAPOR_mean*** which is a 2D variable with shape (***y: 699, x: 639***).

> Xarray took only 10micro seconds to read the data with shape (**Times:2918, lev:36, y:699, x:639**); but took more than 
>   ***60 minutes*** to plot the filled contour of the data of shape (***y: 699, x: 639***).

I am wondering how come Xarray is taking extremely long time (more than 60 mins) to plot the contourf of array with size (***y: 699, x: 639***).

I use following code for reading the files and perform computation.

```
flnm=xr.open_mfdataset('./WRF_3D_2007_*.nc',chunks={'Times': 100})
QVAPOR_mean=flnm.QVAPOR.mean(dim=('Times','lev')
QVAPOR_mean.plot.imshow()
```

The last command takes more than 60 mins to complete. Help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: How big is your total dataset, in GB? `2918 * 36 * 699 * 639 * 8 / 2**30 = 350GB` ? You could play with the chunk sizes, but I'm not sure how much better you could hope for.

Comment: Yes, it is around ~350 GB. I'd already chuck the data along `Time` dimension. The computation is very fast, the only problem is plotting. Python should not take more than few seconds to plot data with shape `(y: 699, x: 639)`. I'm wondering what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you open your dataset and provide the `chunks` argument, xarray is returning a `Dataset` that is comprised of dask arrays. These arrays are evaluated "lazily" ([xarray/dask documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/dask.html)). It is not until you plot your data that the computation is triggered. To illustrate this, you can explicitly load your data after you take the mean:

```
flnm=xr.open_mfdataset('./WRF_3D_2007_*.nc',chunks={'Times': 100})
QVAPOR_mean=flnm.QVAPOR.mean(dim=('Times','lev').load()
```

Now your `QVAPOR_mean` variable is backed by a numpy array instead of a dask array. Plotting this array will likely be much faster.

However, the computation of your `mean` is likely to still take quite a long time. There are ways improve the throughput here as well.

- Try using a larger chunk size. I often find that chunk sizes in the 10-100Mb range perform best.
- Try a different scheduler. You are by default using dask's threaded scheduler. Because of limitations with netCDF/HDF, this does not allow for parallel reads from disk. We have been finding that the `distributed` scheduler works well for these applications.